# Live tile refresh frequency of the Windows 8 weather app

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Anybody knows how often the weather forecast app that is pre-installed in Windows 8 refreshes the data on the live tile? I'm trying to create a small weather app, and I'm getting weather data from a c# webservice(asmx). I want to refresh the data every 5-10 minutes. Right now, I have created a Background task which allows me to refresh the data every 15 minutes, but I don't like the fact that the user has the option to turn on/of the background task. It looks like the Windows 8 weather app is not using a background task.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pre-installed weather app is using [periodic tile updates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779721.aspx) to update it's live tile every 30 minutes.  A background task is not necessary with periodic updates - once periodic updates are set up by an app, Windows will retrieve the new live tile content whether the app is running or not.

Refreshing the data every 5-10 minutes seems a bit excessive.  For a weather app, it shouldn't be necessary to update the tile more frequently than every 30 minutes.

That being said, if you want to update the tile more frequently than every 30 minutes, you'll need to employ either a background task, or push notifications.  Each have their drawbacks.  Background tasks have a minimum 15 minute granularity, and as you stated in your question, can be made to run less frequently by the user.  Push notifications add complexity, but can be used to deliver immediate live tile updates.

Push notifications and periodic updates are in the same [C# sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Push-and-periodic-de225603) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer! In my case it would be desirable to update faster than 30 min. do you know any examples for push notifications in a custom webservice? I have my own C# webservice but i havent found any examples on how to implement in such web services, most examples i see are azure.

Comment: Azure's just a 'hoster' in this context so the concepts are still relevant. I tackle a from-the-ground-up scenario [in a few posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/11/07/windows-8-notifications-push-notifications-via-windows-azure-web-sites-part-1.aspx) here that may be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately these are the parameters a third-party app such as your has to deal with.  The Weather app that is pre-installed is not subject to these limitations since it is a Microsoft app - they aren't subject to the same limitations that we are.